# Combining PNG images while preserving transparency

Tags: php, png, transparency, gd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Combining images in PHP while retaining transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224845/combining-images-in-php-while-retaining-transparency)

Have a look here: http://tyilo.jbusers.com/PNG/progress.php?l=100&p=20

I want to remove the white-thingy at the end of the blue part, but I have tried many different things that didn't work.

If needed the pngs can be found in http://tyilo.jbusers.com/PNG/ folder (http://tyilo.jbusers.com/PNG/Empty.png)

```
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo imagepng(progressbar($_GET['l'], $_GET['p']));
function progressbar($length, $percentage)
{
$length = round($length / 2) * 2;
$percentage = min(100, max(0, $percentage));
if($length > 0)
{
    $bar = imagecreate($length, 14);
    $empty = imagecreatefrompng('Empty.png');
    $fill = imagecreatefrompng('Fill.png');
    $lempty = imagecreatefrompng('LeftEmpty.png');
    $lfill = imagecreatefrompng('LeftFill.png');
    $rempty = imagecreatefrompng('RightEmpty.png');
    $rfill = imagecreatefrompng('RightFill.png');
    $emptycaplength = min(7, $length / 2); //5 
    imagecopy($bar, $lempty, 0, 0, 0, 0, $emptycaplength, 14);
    imagecopy($bar, $rempty, $length - $emptycaplength, 0, 7 - $emptycaplength, 0, $emptycaplength, 14);
    if($length > 14)
    {
        imagecopyresized($bar, $empty, 7, 0, 0, 0, $length - 14, 14, 1, 14);
    }
    $filllength = round(($length * ($percentage / 100)) / 2) * 2;
    $fillcaplength = min(7, $filllength / 2);
    imagecopy($bar, $lfill, 0, 0, 0, 0, $fillcaplength, 14);
    imagecopy($bar, $rfill, $filllength - $fillcaplength, 0, 7 - $fillcaplength, 0, $fillcaplength, 14);
    if($filllength > 14)
    {
        imagecopyresized($bar, $fill, 7, 0, 0, 0, $filllength - 14, 14, 1, 14);
    }
    return $bar;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try GD's function for transparency ?

```
imagealphablending($im,FALSE);
imagesavealpha($im,TRUE);
```

Comment: @Tyilo : after every png **creations** you want to keep with transparency when merging.

Comment: What it looks like: http://cl.ly/566Z  What i want it to look like: http://cl.ly/56OF